# how to do iis 7.0 CLEAN reinstall on vista?

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista, installation

I need to reinstall IIS 7.0 on Vista due to some unsolved configuration issues.

I thought it was easy: I uninstalled all IIS-related stuff in Programs/Features, restarted system, installed all IIS modules again (installation cd wasn't needed) and hmm.. everything looks the same - I mean wrong. I see all configured websites, modules, pools etc.

Is there any clever way to get CLEAN installation with CLEAN database / metabase / configuration files / clean installation files?
Reinstalling whole OS is not a good solution.

Best regards,

Tomek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem and formatting my hard drive was not an option.

The answer is already provided in a comment, and that is **uninstalling** the **Windows Activation Services** in the Windows Components *before* reinstalling IIS.

I hope this helps some of people out there, because i noticed we're not the only ones when googling the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that all configuration in IIS7 is done in the different web.config files. So keeping them will keep your (miss-)configuration after a reinstall.